# Jquery mouseenter within mouseenter

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code which upon hover over an item, brings into view 3 menu options within the item. Standard stuff.

Now, it also hightlights the item hovered over by lowering the css of the rest of the items. This works well but is actually too much and the page ends up flashing like a beacon! So, I want the items `#tiles li` to change opacity when mouse enter either `gl_comments gl_like or gl_readd` which have appeared when hover on one of the 'tiles'

Do I need to write a whole new `mouseenter` function within the current `mouseenter` function? If so, how do I select just the parent 'tile'?

Currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("mouseenter", "#tiles li", function ()
    {
    $(this).children(".gl_comments").fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).children(".gl_readd").fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).children(".gl_like").fadeIn("fast");
    $('#tiles li').css({opacity: '0.1'});
    $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
    });

    $("body").on("mouseleave", "#tiles li", function ()
    {
    $(this).children(".gl_comments").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).children(".gl_readd").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).children(".gl_like").fadeOut("fast");
    $('#tiles li').css({opacity: '1'});
    });
});
```

Comment: I would need to see how your html is set up for the hover over section, `gl_comments`, `gl_like`, and `gl_readd`

Comment: Why don't you use jqueryui menu instead of reinventing the wheel http://jqueryui.com/menu/, or is there any specific behavior you are expecting?